# Understanding registers

Tags: c, uint32, code-composer

I am reading code someone else wrote and I am confused with how they defined their registers the code goes like this:

```
Uint32 GCRO;

Unit32     ; 7U;
```

I don't understand what the second line means.
The code repeats with different named registers and then the `Uint32    ;7U;` line again.
Any help understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense like this, post some context...

Comment: The second line means: `compile error`

Comment: @PeterJ not necessary true!

Comment: @tilz0R it is the code composer. It has this type defined in his std.h or xdas.h files. In common use by TI uC users :)

Comment: Are you sure this is C code and not something else?

Answer (score 1):

In the C language, `Unit32     ; 7U;` is not one, but two unrelated expressions, since the semi-colon separates them.

Depending on how `Uint32` is defined, this doesn't seem like valid C code. Most likely it is defined as `typedef unsigned long Uint32`, in which case `Unit32     ;` won't compile.

`7U;` is valid C, even though it is a dummy line with no effect. It is equivalent to writing

```
(unsigned int)7;
```

Comment: Dont forget: `#define Unit32 do { printf("OmG!\n" ); } while(0)`

Comment: @joop That's the point here. If we assume that they wrote a sane typedef for `Uint32` then it won't compile. If it is some sort of highly obscure macro, then well... you wouldn't want to use their code anyway.

Comment: In fact any code which doesn't use `uint32_t` from stdint.h, but instead some home-brewed version, is either very old or fishy.